# How to use aggregate functions as filter conditions when querying a DFS table in DolphinDB?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, where-clause, database-partitioning, dolphindb

I want to deduplicate the DFS table `t_dk_day_zz985` by column “secode“ and “securityid”.

```
tt = select secode,securityid as instrument from t_dk_day_zz985 where tradetime between 2018.01.01 : 2021.05.31 and isDuplicated([ secode, securityid ], FIRST) == false
```

Here I use column tradetime and securityid as the sort columns.

Then the error is reported:

```
The where clause [tradetime between 2018.01.01 : 2021.05.31 and isDuplicated([ secode, securityid ], FIRST) == 0] of a distributed/partitioned sql shouldn't use any aggregate or order-sensitive function.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised because aggregate functions or order-sensitive functions cannot be used in the where conditions of queries on DFS tables. For queries across partitions, you can specify the filter conditions with `map` keyword. The SQL statement is executed separately in each partition, and then the result of each partition is output.

```
tt = select secode,securityid as instrument from t_dk_day_zz985 where tradetime between 2018.01.01 : 2021.05.31 and isDuplicated([ secode, securityid ], FIRST) == false map
```